# Trusted Application API (Skype for Business) - Invite licenced user to adhoc meeting

Tags: api, callback, skype-for-business, ucwa, trusted-application

I am trying to create anonymous chat application for Skype for Business.

Folowed [Trusted Application API (Skype for Business) – Authentication and Online Meetings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2017/04/13/skype-for-business-trusted-application-api-tutorial/) tutorial i got everything working, except I cant invite licenced Skype for business user nor start conferencing.

When I call **service:joinAdhocMeeting** url, callback script catches response containing **service:addParticipant** url - something like:

```
https://webpoolbl20r04.infra.lync.com/platformservice/tgt-5b7d56427fde560091ff724dd7e3d410/v1/applications/522422585/communication/participantInvitations?endpointId=sip:webchat@myorg.com&conversationId=e8285886-d0a5-4bf2-ea64-7f74774ea451
```

Posting json payload to link:

```
{
    operationId: 'd51285886-d0a5-4bf2-ea64-7f74774ea451',
    to: 'sip:whoIwantToInvite',
}
```

Gives me back:

```
 HTTP response 201 CREATED
```

Once done, callback catches two more events

- information that **service:participantInvitation** started
- just a second later **service:participantInvitation** failure

Displayed reason is:

```
reason: {
    code: "Timeout",
    message: "The operation was timed out."
},
```

When I try **service:startMessaging** instead of creating adhoc meeting, I endup with same Timeout error as described above.

Skype for Business user who is invited is definitely online, and if I do open **joinUrl** of created adhoc meeting manualy, I can join to conversation without any problem.

Have you encountered same behaviour? Is there any 'server side' log for Skype for Business online, where I can turn to?

Comment: The invited user is online, but are you sure that they have accepted the invitation?

Comment: @JohnAustin I am inviting me - running SFB client app at my computer, invitation screen does not pop-up at all. Already tried with few different accounts, even with completly different tennant with fresh Trusted App registration. Everytime I invite someone, I get timeout error message.